# How to pass a complex object between render-thread & updater thread?

Tags: java, synchronized, volatile

I have a complex object let's call it `World` that contains other objects with players data, objects describing the world map etc. It's used for a turn-based game where I render the `World` on the screen but use a separate thread to update the `World` each turn as this takes a few seconds to run. Running it all in the render thread would simply freeze the screen.

This is how the `World` is updated in non-render thread and the passed back to the render thread:

```
// copy the world that is used for rendering
World world;
synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
  world = Renderer.this.world;
}
World clone = Util.clone(world);

// update the world 
Updater.update(clone);

// pass the updated world back to the render thread
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
      Renderer.this.world = clone;
    }
  }
});
```

This is how the render works:

```
// member variable: our sync-object
public final Object sync = new Object();

// member variable for world
public World world;

public void render() {
  ... renders the world object...
}
```

Here are my questions:

- Does this properly pass back the new world object to the render thread? I am pretty sure that the reference to the newly cloned world is correct, but do the contents of that cloned world synchronize to the world object as well?
- Should "volatile" be used and how?
- is for example `world.getPlayer(index).getName()` properly synchronized?

Not sure if the question is clear? I'll clarify as needed. - Thanks!

Comment: Not enough code: what is `runInRenderThread()`? The syntax is a bit weird—looks like a cross between a method call and an anonymous class instantiation. How does the renderer thread work? Is it some sort of infinite loop that is event-based or what? Does it work directly with the member field or does it also copy the reference using a `synchronized` block?

Comment: It's OpenGL but it works the same as `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)`. Basically pass-back is called within the render-thread. I updated the example. Although it's not Swing, it works the same way.

Comment: If you are making deep copies of the entire `World` anyway, I would suggest making `World` (and everything contained within) immutable. That saves you a lot of headaches about synchronization and all you need to worry about is publishing (and picking up) your `World` reference safely.

Comment: Another thing I would do is to extract all the logic about handing a `World` over into its own separate class, which would make the code more readable and testable.

Comment: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` accepts a `Runnable` as its parameter. The thing you had before had no parameters, but had a weird `{}` part *after* the parameters (instead of the usual comma), that's what confused me.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a course on Spring framework.  The lecturer went to great length to prove to us that developing multi-threaded applications is extremely complex. Even if you think you wrapped every piece of sensitive code in synchronized block, you might get unexpected behavior because of run time optimizations (like branch prediction and such)

The volatile keyword is used to control such unpredicted behavior (i.e. put a barrier on branch prediction parallel processing)

I put a disclaimer on my answer that I do not have much experience developing multi-threaded applications.  Having said that, I would design the World object as a singleton so that there is only one copy of it and only one thread has access to it at one time.

Answer (score 0):

More clarification is needed to answer your first question because the code is unclear. However, to your second question I can say that you can do it in three ways here:

1. Using `synchronized` as you seem to do here (except that you don't show us your renderer code, so I can't be sure about that).
2. Using `volatile`.
3. Using an `AtomicReference`.

Any of these will do, but you need to be careful and do everything right. You seem to be very careful about not modifying the world directly, but rather taking a copy of it and modify that locally before publishing the reference. That's a good thing. But then you do something strange. I expect to see something like this instead:

```
synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
  world = Renderer.this.world;
}
World clone = Util.clone(world);
// update the world 
Updater.update(clone);
// publish the reference back to the renderer
synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
  Renderer.this.world = clone;
}
```

It is all done in the non-renderer thread. *Then,* after you publish the reference you should notify the renderer somehow so it copies the published reference to a local variable (again, in a `synchronized` block) and then renders it. This way you ensure that it gets the world that is correctly updated *and* the `world` reference is never hot-swapped during the rendering process.

This is all about basically two operations: reading a reference shared between two threads and writing it. There is the thing called [*happens-before relationship*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5). Applicable to this case:

- an unlock on a monitor happens-before every subsequent lock on that monitor;
- a write to a volatile field (§8.3.1.4) happens-before every subsequent read of that field;
- `AtomicReference.set` happens before every subsequent `AtomicReference.get` (according to [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html), get and set have the same semantics as volatile reads/writes).

That's why you could do exactly the same thing using a `volatile` field or an `AtomicReference` (both will provide better performance than `synchronized`). Just replace those `synchronized` assignment blocks with a `volatile` assignment or calls to set/get of the atomic reference.

Now, we are talking about writes/reads of the reference itself. What about the fields of the `world` or the objects that it references? Well, things happening in one thread also have happens-before relationship as they come in the program order. Therefore, whatever you write to the fields of the `world` object (or anything belonging to its object graph, or anywhere else for that matter) *before* you publish the reference to the clone, will be visible to the rendering thread:

```
clone.setSomeProperty(someValue); // this...
synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
    Renderer.this.world = clone; // ...happens-before this, which in turn...
}
// ...
synchronized (Renderer.this.sync) {
    world = Renderer.this.world; // ...happens-before this in the rendering thread
    // (assuming the rendering thread entered this block after the
    //  updating thread entered its block, otherwise we'll just see
    //  the old world here and will pick up the new one on the next try)
}
```

What will happen if you pass the `clone` variable to the other thread directly, using a closure such as an anonymous `Runnable` passed to `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`? It depends on how `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` is implemented. Unfortunately, the docs aren't terribly clear on that subject. My guess it's safe, but to be absolutely sure I'd rather published the new reference safely from the current thread (as in the example above) or, alternatively, relied on `final` field semantics, like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  private final World world = clone; // final semantics enforced
  public void run() {
    Renderer.this.world = world; // this runs after the Runnable is constructed
    // and therefore is guaranteed to see the updated version of the world
  }
});
```

You should consult the docs about the OpenGL function you use to execute code in the renderer thread. If it says that the invocation of the `runInRenderThread()` happens-before the code is executed, then you're safe. Otherwise, better do something like above, although they probably just forgot to mention the details in the docs. Such mechanisms are designed to pass things from one thread to another so they almost always enforce the happens-before relationship (typically using some sort of concurrent queue).

Lastly, one thing you should never, ever do is modify the world after you published its reference one way or another to the renderer thread. This will break the happens-before relationship and may lead to inconsistencies. So none of that “Oh, wait, I've already published it, but I need to update this important field ASAP!”—sorry, that will have to wait until the next update.

Comment: I think I see what you are getting at. However, I assume your "synchronized" part would put it into `Renderer.this.newWorld` which will then again be taken and replaced with `Renderer.this.world` by the render-thread? Would `AtomicReference` also make sure the contents of the world, e.g. `world.getPlayer(index).getName()` are up-to-date? Is this not only the reference itself?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by replacing `Renderer.this.world` with `Renderer.this.world` by the render-thread. I'm talking about two operations here: read and write. The updating thread reads the reference, produces a new version and then writes it. The rendering thread just reads the reference as it needs it. And yes, `volatile` (as of Java 5 and later) or `AtomicReference` will provide the up-to-date copy of the world as long as nobody modifies it after the reference is published. I'll edit my answer to clarify these points.